# Unable to process binding when binding datatables with knockoutjs

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, datatables

I am trying to use jquery datatables with knockoutjs. the datatables grid renders fine, but seeing an error in the console of the browser window. Can some one please help me resolve this issue and correct me if I did something wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/5hwg1p36/

```
**Error:**
knockout-min.js:73 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "dataTable: function(){return { deferRender:true,scrollY:'200',scrollX:true,paging:true,select:Select,dom:'t,p',columns:Columns,columnDefs:ColumnDefinitions,data:Data,pagingType:'full'} }"
Message: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
    at Jb (jquery.dataTables.min.js:68)
    at jQuery.fn.init.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:91)
    at jquery.dataTables.min.js:76
    at Function.map (jquery-3.3.1.js:443)
    at r (jquery.dataTables.min.js:76)
    at P (jquery.dataTables.min.js:31)
    at T (jquery.dataTables.min.js:31)
    at ha (jquery.dataTables.min.js:48)
    at e (jquery.dataTables.min.js:93)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:93)

[JS Fiddle for this issue is here: ][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/5hwg1p36/
```

Comment: Add your code example please

Comment: Code is at http://jsfiddle.net/5hwg1p36/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because you tried to add a new column whose `title` property is `null`. jQuery DataTables requires that property to be **not null**.

The fix is quite simple, just change `title: null` to `title: ""`. In your fiddle it's on line `35`.

```
self.Columns.push({
    data: null, 
    title: "", // this property cannot be null, so use empty string instead
    searchable: false, 
    visible: true, 
    orderable: false, 
    defaultContent: ''
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5hwg1p36/1/

Comment: Thank you, Appreciate your help.